# How do I get pexpect to match everything BUT a given line?

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

Let's say there's a call to pexpect.expect like this:

```
ret = pex.expect([re.escape(line), pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout)
if ret == 0:
    do_stuff()
elif ret == 1:
    do_eof_stuff()
elif ret == 2:
    do_timeout_stuff()
```

Instead of matching the line I'm interested in, I want to switch things around and match anything BUT that line, in addition to handling EOF and TIMEOUT. Sort of like this:

```
ret = pex.expect([not re.escape(line), pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout)
if ret == 0:
    do_error_stuff()
elif ret == 1:
    do_eof_stuff()
elif ret == 2:
    do_timeout_stuff()
else:
   # Our line "matched" so do stuff
   do_stuff()
```

I know 'not re.escape(line)' isn't valid, it's just a way to demonstrate what I want. What would I actually use in it's place?

Comment: use a regular expression that accepts everything except something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I toyed around with this using a negative lookahead:

```
ret = pex.expect([r'^((?!' + re.escape(line) + ').)*$', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout)
```

The caveat here is that if line was `hello world` for example:

```
hello world -> won't match
hello world 2 -> won't match
my hello world -> won't match
hello worl -> will match
```

Not sure how specific you need that.